# Do you have a 3Ddata of crop_and_resize function implementation? DATA of shape [batch, depth, image_height, image_width, channel]

Tags: python, tensorflow

Do you have a 3Ddata of `crop_and_resize` function implementation? DATA of shape `[batch, dim1, dim2, dim3, channel]`. If not, how to implement this function in tensorflow.

On 3D data, I deduct the corresponding area of each box from the feature graph. The number of BOX of an input image is unknown, the dimension of box is `[None, cord-dim]`, and the number of boxes is `None`, because the input data is placed holder. So it is not feasible to use two-dimensional `crop_and_resize` functions.

```
# labels_mask_box:  N * 6

roi_align(tf.expand_dims(netconv4[i, ...], axis=0), labels_mask_box[..., :] , crop_szie)
tf.image.crop_and_resize(image, boxes, box_ind,crop_size=[crop_size, crop_size])
```